how to let client type their email address on Stripe Terminal
I folks, I'm working on a subscription solution and the client just received some terminals from Stripe.
They want to let the client type their emails and flip the card into the terminal to finish the payment.
I'm trying to use the stripe terminal simulator protect however the the project does not detect any "simulated-reader", which is already created on the test environment inside the stripe dashboard.
The project uses NodeJS with StripeCLI.
Anybody already created anything similar?.
On the following link docs.stripe.com/api/terminal/readers/collect_inputs stripe says this feature is on Beta, but seems to be possible to realize.
Thanks!

It's not possible to prompt for your own inputs on a reader via a typical Stripe Terminal integration.
You will need to explore building an app for your POS flow leveraging their Apps on Devices offering:
https://docs.stripe.com/terminal/features/apps-on-devices/overview

Thanks Toby, however on the Stipe documentation exists a new feature called custom input collect which seems to allow what I need.
